# Azure Graph API - Query user information

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to figure out how to use the Azure Graph API to query a user's full name (first and last) from a given username.  I understand I can do this with the following Graph API call...

```
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{user_id}?api-version
```

However, I am not sure how I go about getting an access token to use with this, because this process will be called without a user logging in, which is usually how we obtain an access token.

Is there anyway I can pass a username/password to a given URL using cURL or something and obtain an access token that way, so it is done behind-the-scenes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main authentication methods which are supported by OAuth 2:

1. [Authorization Code Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1) Flow
2. [Client Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4) Flow

The first flow requires a user agent to be present to sign into the client service and results in a *delegated token*. The second method does not require a user to sign in, as it only authenticates using the client secret; this results in an *app only token*.

If you want to create a background service that captures data from the AAD Graph API, you can absolutely do this using the Client Credentials Grant Flow, which does not require a user to be present at any point during the authentication flow.

You simply need to configure your application to to have *app only scopes*. Read [here: Permission scopes | Graph API concepts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-permission-scopes). App only scopes all require tenant administrators to consent to the application in order to get access to data.

Finally, I feel I must mention that there is another less used flow specified in the OAuth 2 spec: [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3). This flow specifies how a client application who has knowledge of a user's username and password could directly pass those parameters and get an access token on behalf of the user. However using this flow is not good practice at all.

> The resource owner password credentials grant type is suitable in
> cases where the resource owner has a trust relationship with the
> client, such as the device operating system or a highly privileged
> application.  The authorization server should take special care when
> enabling this grant type and only allow it when other flows are not
> viable.

We support this in our V1 endpoint, but not in our new V2 endpoint. You can read [this blog to learn more](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/).